# Check database every hour and push notification

Tags: database, parse-platform, push-notification, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I am currently building a cross-platform application using Xamarin.Forms and the Parse database. I already have a working matching algorithm but for now it is being executed only on a button click. I want to make it execute every hour in order to check for changes in the database. If there is a match for the current user then a notification should be pushed. The application should still do this even if it's closed. Is this possible and if it is how can I implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. First thing you should do is read this guide on CloudCode.

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

You'll set it up so that it runs every hour (background job). Then your CloudCode function will send a push notification to the phones that have a match (if I'm understanding you correctly).

In Cloud Code it would look like:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery, // A Parse.Query that sets which phones receive the push
    data: {

    }, {
    success: function() {
        // Push sent correctly
    }, error: function(error) {
        // Handle error 
    }
});
```

Hopefully this will be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Also, just to be even more specific, https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs is the background job section which is what you need it seems like